# How to click on the button as per the HTML provided?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

This is the html code for the button in the pop up ( pop up has a lead gen form) -

```
<button id="getCoupon" class="fetch" data-bind="click: submitForm" type="submit">Fetch Coupon</button>
```

This is the script which I have written in JAVA in Eclipse. I am able to fill the name, Email and Phone number but I'm not able to click on the button -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("getCoupon")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment and URL, you have shared :

You can try with this code :

```
public class Pawan  {

    static WebDriver driver ; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user**\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://vets.cm.qa.preview.vca.webstagesite.com/free-first-exam");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[value='/santa-monica']~div.select-btn"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("fName"))).sendKeys("Pawan");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lName"))).sendKeys("Sharma");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("email"))).sendKeys("ps12@gmail.com");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("zip"))).sendKeys("90404");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("phone"))).sendKeys("9697989900");  

        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100)", "");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("getCoupon"))).click();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It works perfectly fine, But I checked it in Firefox! It's working for you?

Comment: @Rajagopalan : I have checked this in chrome and it works fine for me though. Thank for your help.  I just wanted to verify , now it is upto the OP.

Comment: Okay great, He is making some minor mistake I guess!

Comment: @Rajagopalan : May be. That's why I have given him full code. let's see

Comment: I have already given, it's been a bigger conversation here, it was moved to chat section, it's not working for him! I checked in both browser chrome and firefox but nothing seems to be working for him.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : in that case what is the error he's getting ? Thanks for you input.

Comment: He says he is not getting any error, it clicks but it's not moving to other page. I don't face such an issue and now you confirmed too1

Comment: @Rajagopalan : We have already spent too much time in that. Now leave it . Let him revert back to us now.

Comment: @cruisepandey : I run your code and found that his is not opening the Popup even. It is just typing the zipcode in search box and nothing. By the way thanks for all for your efforts.

Comment: Hey All, Code posted by me is working very fine for me. It is opening the pop-up, filling all the details, but just not clicking the fetch button.

Comment: @PawanSharma :Did you try my answer ?

Comment: @cruisepandey : Thank you very much. your code is working for me. we can close this discussion now. thanks again

Comment: @cruisepandey : Can you please help, what is difference in your code and mine code. What special we need to use here ?

Comment: @cruisepandey : your code is working for me, but you didn't write the code to enter a zipcode like : 12345 in text box and hit enter. and then we need to click on select button.While i edit your code and insert the code for enter zipcode then your code is not working for me ::::::: Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
   driver.findElement(By.id("searchLocation")).sendKeys("12345");   
   new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();

Comment: I have written code for zip `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("zip"))).sendKeys("90404");`

Comment: Application will not accept `12345` as zip number because , it is taking only valid zip number.

Answer (score 0):

As per your HTML code, your id is : "getCoupon",
whereas in code you mentioned id as : "getCouponFetch". Please correct and it should work. Code -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("getCoupon")).click();
```

If selenium click don't work, use below Java Script click code :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("getCoupon")); JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177040/discussion-on-answer-by-hemendra-how-to-click-on-the-button-as-per-the-html-prov).

Comment: I saw you have written to @DebanjanB but you haven't put at infront of his name, May be add an @ symbol, he may come on your way to help you!

Comment: It perfectly works for me so I am left with no way to help you, I am sorry! I hope @DebanjanB will help you!

Comment: @Rajagopalan : Can you do me a favor , just run my code for this question and let me know if the execution was successful. Thank you !

Comment: @cruisepandey Okay, sure!

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to `click()` on the button you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.fetch#getCoupon"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='fetch' and @id='getCoupon'][contains(.,'Fetch Coupon')]"))).click();
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can use the `executeScript()` method to invoke the `click()` as follows:

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement fetch_coupon = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.fetch#getCoupon")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", fetch_coupon);
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement fetch_coupon = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='fetch' and @id='getCoupon'][contains(.,'Fetch Coupon')]")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", fetch_coupon);
  ```

Comment: @PawanSharma : it never makes sense when you say this is not working. Show some efforts . You should post error stack trace if there is any.

Comment: @debanjan I'm not getting any error. The thing is the script is not clicking the button.

Comment: Can you update the question exactly which element are yo trying to clck on the _webpage_?

Comment: I'm trying to click on this button :<button id="getCoupon" class="fetch" data-bind="click: submitForm" type="submit">Fetch Coupon</button>

Comment: This element is no visible on the webpage, update the question with the _Manual Steps_ before you attempt to click on the element.

Comment: open the page :http://vets.cm.qa.preview.vca.webstagesite.com/free-first-exam.  now click on selete button from right side. And fill the data and then we need to click on fetch button of that popup.

Comment: @PawanSharma Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what kind of error did you get??

Try using implicit wait if your getting "**NoSuchElementException**" like below:

```
driver.manage().timeOuts().implicitlywait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then try using the below way to locate that button:

```
driver.findElementByXpath("text()[contains(.,'Fetch Coupon')]").click();
```